# Convert interactive flash animation to javascript to use in html5

Tags: javascript, html, flash

Hi,

I have a banner on my site made in flash. Its an animation that ends with a sequence showing buttons which the user can click to navigate to inner pages. Since flash seems to be dead soon I would like to replace that with html5 friendly code. Is it possible to have a program such as Adobe Flash CS5 to convert the full movie for me into javascript code? Or I have to write the javascript all by myself from scratch?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you even search google? https://developers.google.com/swiffy/?hl=en

Comment: Thanks but thats not what I expected. The result is impressive but the code is like 1 million km long.. I was expecting a combination of javascript and images so I can have a shorter and cleaner code.

Comment: If it is exporting images as _data URIs_ within the script (looks like `data:mime,content`) then they are reasonably easy (though maybe tedious) to export and re-write as URLs. If it is the logic which becomes long and you find unacceptable then you'll need to re-write it manually

Comment: Thats what I thought. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Flash CC to publish you flash file into HTML canvas base structure. Steps -

1. Open file in Flash CC select commands->Convert to other Documents.
2. Folder Select HTML 5 Canvas from Dropdown and press OK. Now open
3. newly created Flash file and publish. It will give you the canvas
   base html file.

The html and javascript you get is in organized format and you can even edit code as well.

Hope it solve your problem.

Comment: flash cc is a later version of flash cs5?

Comment: As Google's Swiffy was abandoned in 2016, this is the perfect solution when using Flash CC (Anime). Watch out to convert all Actionscript 2.0 to 3.0